# How can I display the content of an xml file in html divs with ajax call?

Tags: html, ajax, xml, call, display

I'm working on an online website for contact management and I need to display my contacts from an xml file in html divs. How can I do this using an AJAX CALL, exclusively? My xml looks like this and I want to put this tags in some divs, one div for each contact.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<contacts>
    <contact id_contact="1">
       <firstName>Lara</firstName>
       <lastName>Adey</lastName>
       <photo>lara.png</photo>
       <email>lara.adey@gmail.com</email>
       <birthday>1999-03-12</birthday>
       <adress>Brooklyn 99</adress>
       <description>Nice girl</description> 
       <phone>520-447-9821</phone>
       <interests>Coding</interests>
       <idUser>2</idUser>
    </contact>
</contacts>
```

Comment: You might want to look at https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/ is you are using jQuery and just need something pretty simple.  You would have to parse the file and create HTML from the values in the file.  Also:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16113188/convert-xml-to-html-using-jquery-javascript

Comment: You can read further on this: https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_xmlfile.asp

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your javascript using JQuery $.ajax
Documentation : http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "contacts.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: xmlParse
   });
});

function xmlParse(xml) {

$(xml).find("contact").each(function () {
    $(".main").append('<div class="contact"><div class="firstname">' + $(this).find("firstName").text() + '</div><div class="lastName">' + $(this).find("lastName").text() + '</div><div class="photo">Photo ' +
$(this).find("photo").text() + '</div><div class="email">Email ' +    $(this).find("email").text() +'</div><div class="birthday">Birthday ' +  $(this).find("birthday").text() + '</div><div class="address">Address ' +  $(this).find("address").text() + '</div><div class="description">Description ' +  $(this).find("description").text() + '</div><div class="phone">Phone ' +  $(this).find("phone").text() + '</div><div class="interests">Interests ' + 
$(this).find("interests").text() + '</div><div class="idUser">User ID ' + 
$(this).find("idUser").text() + '</div></div>');
    $(".contact").fadeIn(1000);
 });

}
```

In your HTML :

```html
<div class="main"></div>
```